# How to get height of my ul element? In AngularJS without jQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-lists, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/a7oV4gWzJG532RSqqOt3?p=preview**

I'm building my own infinite scroll ability in an Angular project, and I need to obtain the height of my ul.

Currently I'm using this:

Markup

```
<ul id="tags-list">
  <li ng-repeat="t in tags">
    <div class="tag"
      ng-mouseover="showTagDetails(t)"
      ng-mouseleave="leaveTag(t)"
      ng-click="sendTag(t)">{{t.name}}</div>
    <tag-details tag="t"></tag-details>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Controller

```
if ($scope.tags.length != 0 || $scope.tags.length != undefined) {
    var theHeight = document.getElementById('tags-list').offsetHeight;
    // var h = theHeight.style.height;
    console.log(theHeight);
}
```

`.offsetHeight` is returning `0` for my `ul` for some reason.

`var h = theHeight.style.height;` did not return anything.

I do not want to use *jQuery* here to obtain the height, how would you do this?

Comment: try `document.getElementById('tags-list').clientHeight`

Comment: @SethMcClaine still returns `0` :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the code inside your if statement with $timeout to give Angular the time it needs to change the DOM:

```
$timeout(function(){
  var theHeight = document.getElementById('tags-list').offsetHeight;
  console.log(theHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to display the actual calulated height was to wait for Angular to re-render the DOM by forcing a timeout.

```
if ($scope.tags.length != 0 || $scope.tags.length != undefined) {
    var list= document.getElementById('tags-list');
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log( list.offsetHeight );
    }, 100);
}
```

trevor's answer is better as it is an angular timeout service.

Answer (score 1):

Working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/RH1IBRVoowWFUoWvHGY8?p=preview

Wrap your code around a $timeout call. The DOM has not been yet being updated when your controller is initialized, that's why you need to wrap it with a $timeout.

```
$timeout(function() {
  if ($scope.tags.length != 0 || $scope.tags.length != undefined) {
    var theHeight = document.getElementById('tags-list').offsetHeight;
    // var h = theHeight.style.height;
    console.log(theHeight);
  }
});
```